# wp_insert_user error

Tags: users, errors

Hi before this I using wp_create_user.
It was working properly.

Now I change it little bit of my code
to use wp_insert_user.
I change because i have custom field to set
but now I using standard field , email , pass and username
but got problem when submit

The problem are

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /wp-includes/user.php on line 1764
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /wp-includes/user.php on line 1767

my code
https://codepen.io/rusydi-hakim/pen/XWNeapx

Comment: I think this is just a typo. You're setting up array `$user_data` with an underscore but calling `$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;` with no underscore in `$userdata`.

Comment: Okay thanks, it works